# Need help formulating a question in an acceptable way

Tags: discussion

This question is related to https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/38814/why-is-it-so-hard-to-find-a-good-drummer?noredirect=1#comment55597_38814

Some recent posts have mentioned how difficult it can be to find a good drummer (links provided in the above-referenced question).  The tone of those posts was that the rarity of good drummers is a "truth that is universally acknowledged" (à la Jane Austen).  (But I wasn't aware of this before reading those posts.)

I don't want to get into an argument about whether it's true or not (that it's very difficult to find a good drummer).  I want the people who believe that good drummers are hard to find, to help me understand *why* they are so rare.

My question is about to be closed.  Can folks please help me formulate my question better, so it doesn't get closed, and so it gets some helpful answers?

Answer (score 2):

It was actually closed before I even saw it, but as I would have voted to close as well, I can give my view (in addition to the fairly clear comments you got on that post):

Your basic question is reasonable, but is entirely opinion-based - so it would probably still get closed pretty quickly.

The post you wrote, however, comes across as rude, opinionated, and a bit of a rant against drummers. If these are the thoughts that spring to mind when you ask the question, I am not surprised when people take umbrage. If I were a drummer your post would annoy me.

So with that in mind, why did you feel it was necessary to make a conjecture? If you are asking a question, you don't need to make conjecture that could be taken as insult - why not **just ask the question**?

So, my guidance to you is:

- Avoid the conjecture part - it's unneeded and insulting in this case
- Don't ask why people do things - everyone has different reasons, so that would be opinion based

Comment: I don't play with drummers.  I'm in a completely different sphere of music!  I'm just trying to understand the posts I read, where some people said it's very difficult to find a good drummer.  I want to understand why they said that.  I have no opinion about drumming.  In my conjectures, I was using my imagination to try to figure it out.  //  Now, if you ask me why so many trumpet players have gotten hugely on my nerves over the years, when I have had to sit near them in orchestra, and what makes me *really* appreciate a good trumpet player... then I'll have an opinion of my own.

Comment: That was just an example.  I could also go on and on about what makes a bad conductor bad.  Etc.

Comment: All those conjectures would be a bad idea, for the same reason, and will alienate and annoy people in the same way

Comment: You misunderstand.  I have no reason to want to post any of that.  My question is, how can I construct a question, to find out why those posters complained so bitterly about bad drummers?  Ah, that gives me an idea....

Comment: Okay, I edited the question.  If that still doesn't work, I have another idea for a related question.  But I wanted to say that your Answer explains what was bad about my Question about the bad drummers that other posters had posited.  Note, you're not answering my Meta Question!  An answer this one, one would need to suggest how to re-formulate the Question to make it answerable.

Comment: This is in the standard SE guidance on every site, as we have discussed with you many times, so my answer here covers your specifics in this instance.

Comment: Additionally - I have edited your post to fix it. Simply saying "This is not my opinion" did not help at all.

Comment: Thanks for the edit....  Someone else did some more editing -- did that mess up what you were trying to accomplish?  //  I'd like to see the question reopened once the editing process is complete.